# Use of unresolved identifier 'MapTasks'

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, marker

I wanna add marker in my app in google maps

I have this error

> Use of unresolved identifier 'MapTasks'

[image]

```
var mapView: GMSMapView?
var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
var locationMarker: GMSMarker!
var mapTasks = MapTasks()  ---> error
```

all my problem is that I can't add optional marker when user touch in google maps.

Answer (score -1):

In adding marker when user touch the map, use [`didTapAtCoordinate`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/protocol_g_m_s_map_view_delegate-p.html#member-function-documentation) this was called after a tap gesture at a particular coordinate, but only if a marker was not tapped. Or, `didLongPressAtCoordinate` when long press gesture at a particular coordinate.

To [add a marker](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker), you need to create a `GMSMarker` object that includes a `position` and `title` and set its `map`.

The following example demonstrates how to add a marker to an existing GMSMapView object. The marker is created at coordinates 10,10, and displays the string "Hello world" in an info window when clicked.

```
let position = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(10, 10)
let marker = GMSMarker(position: position)
marker.title = "Hello World"
marker.map = mapView
```

Here's a related SO ticket, discuss regarding touch event: [Google Maps iOS SDK Touch Events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29047860/google-maps-ios-sdk-touch-events)